# SQL server query to get the list of columns in a table along with Data types, NOT NULL, and PRIMARY KEY,Foreignkey constraints in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

How to write this query to display all columns with the given properties and constraints,
My expected output is:

**Column name | Data type | Length | isnull | Pk | FK**

Answer (score 0):

All that you want is already done in `sp_help`.

You execute it passing it `table` name like this:

```
exec sp_help 'MyTable'
```

If you want to have another `resultset` you can extract all the `queries` from `sp_help`:

```
exec sp_helptext 'sp_help'
```

And ajust these `queries` to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you wanted

```
use [*MyDBName*]    
  Select Column_name, 
         data_type, 
         Character_maximum_length, 
         (Select Tab.Constraint_name 
          from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab 
          left join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE ColU on Tab.Constraint_name = colU.Constraint_name       
          where Tab.Table_name = Col.Table_name AND ColU.COLUMN_NAME = Col.Column_name  and Tab.CONSTRAINT_NAME like 'Pk[_]%'
         )  PK,
         (Select Tab.Constraint_name 
          from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab 
          left join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE ColU on Tab.Constraint_name = colU.Constraint_name       
          where Tab.Table_name = Col.Table_name AND ColU.COLUMN_NAME = Col.Column_name  and Tab.CONSTRAINT_NAME like 'Fk[_]%'
         )  FK
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns Col
  WHERE Col.TABLE_NAME = '*MyTableName*'
```

Answer (score 0):

For a particular table's columns

```
select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, character_maximum_length, is_nullable from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
```

For all tables columns

```
select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, character_maximum_length, is_nullable from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

For contraints

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE where table_name ='Table_name'
```